# Let $a_0,a_1,a_2$ be rationals, $\det\begin{pmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2\\a_2&a_0+a_1&a_1+a_2\\a_1&a_2&a_0+a_1\end{pmatrix}=0$, show $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, determinant

> Let $a_0,a_1,a_2$ be rationals, $\det\begin{pmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2\\a_2&a_0+a_1&a_1+a_2\\a_1&a_2&a_0+a_1\end{pmatrix}=0$, show $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$.

This is a problem in PHD candidate to PKU (2019).

The matrix is not invariant under permutations of $1,2,3$. So I could not just let the last column being the linear combination of the first two. Soundly, I have no idea. Any hint is grateful.

Comment: If any row has all its elements zero, the determinant is also zero.

Comment: @SubhamKarmakar Then what to do? We need to show $a_i=0$, $\forall\ i$.

Comment: @SubhamKarmakar Your comment is off target. There are certainly matrices with zero determinant which do not have *any* row with all elements zero. OP is only assuming that particular matrix of rational entries is zero, then trying to *deduce* from that the elements of its first (and therefore the others) row are all zero.

Comment: Could you stop making insignificant edits to the title of this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

I suggest first to permute $a_1$ and $a_2$, getting the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_0&a_2&a_1\\a_1&a_0+a_2&a_1+a_2\\a_2&a_1&a_0+a_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, consider the ring
$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-x-1)$$
Since the polynomial $x^3 - x -1$ is irreducible, we get in fact a field.

The multiplication by an element $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ has the above matrix in the basis $1$, $x$, $x^2$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Another solution in the style of linear algebra.

Consider the matrix
$$X=
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0& 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

( the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $x^3 - x -1$)

Then our matrix equals
$$A = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2$$

Let's diagonalize $X$. Consider $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ the roots of the polynomial $x^3 - x -1$. Then one can check that
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\
1 & \beta & \beta^2\\
1  & \gamma  & \gamma^2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot X = \operatorname{Diag}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\
1 & \beta & \beta^2\\
1  & \gamma  & \gamma^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $X$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $a_0 + a_1 \alpha + a_2 \alpha^2, \ldots$. We conclude that
$$\det A= (a_0 + a_1 \alpha + a_2 \alpha^2)(a_0 + a_1 \beta + a_2 \beta^2) ( a_0 + a_1 \gamma + a_2 \gamma^2)$$

Now we use that $x^3 - x -1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so neither of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ is root of a rational polynomial of degree $\le 2$.

Let's note that the determinant equals the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) of the element $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ in the field $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - x -1)$

$$N^K_{\mathbb{Q}}(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2) = \det A $$

$\bf{Added:}$  Another solution:

Note that we may assume $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ integers (with $\gcd = 1$). We used the polynomial $x^3 - x -1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. But the polynomial is also irreducible $\mod 2$. We could have worked over the basic field $\mathbb{Z}/2$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$ and still get the same result. This suggests that we can show the result $\mod 2$. Therefore, we can show: if $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ are integers, not all even then the above determinant is odd. Indeed the determinant equals
$$\det A = a_0^3 + 2 a_0 ^3 a_3 - a_0 a_1^2 - 3 a_0 a_1 a_2 + a_0 a_2^2 + a_1^3 - a_1 a_2^2 + a_3^3 $$

(see this WA [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%5B%7B%20%7B%20a%2C%20c%2C%20b%7D%2C%20%7Bb%2C%20a%2Bc%2C%20b%2Bc%7D%2C%20%7Bc%2C%20b%2C%20a%2Bc%7D%7D%5D)). Now, if the $a_i$ are in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ then the expression equals
$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_0 a_1 + a_0 a_2 + a_1 a_2 + a_0 a_1 a_2 = (1+a_0)(1+ a_1)(1+a_2) + 1$$
and this equals $1 \pmod 2$ if at least one of the $a_i$ is $1 \pmod 2$.  We are done.

Comment: Is there any linear algebra proof?

Comment: Let us set $a_0=x,a_1=y,a_2=z$ and solve the determinant equation, which leads to $x^3+2 x^2 y+x y^2+y^3+z^3-z \left(x (3 y+z)+y^2\right)=0$. Maybe this can be a starting point for showing $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is the solution?

Comment: @xldd: Just added one.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow: The expression factors into a product of $3$ linear forms, with coefficients involving the roots of $x^3 - x -1$. Now we can use the irreducibility of this polynomial. The trick is the factoring.

Comment: $X$ is the companion matrix of $x^3-x-1$ which is therefore its minimal polynomial. This is the reason for the ring $R=\{a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2:a_0,a_1,a_2\in\mathbb Q\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3-x-1)$.

Comment: @user26857: Yes, indeed!!  added that.

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow: It is enough to check that there are no non-zero integral solutions, with $\gcd=1$. Now, this can be checked already $\mod 2$.

Comment: @orangeskid: You mean $\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}-x$ (meaning $0=x^3-2x-4$) has no non-zero solutions (with $\gcd=1$)?

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow: I mean that the determinant (in $x$, $y$, $z$) has no integral solutions non-zero solutions, and it is true in fact $\mod 2$.

Comment: @orangeskid: Ahh understood now, sorry for confusion.